# Intersection of a constant positive Gauss curvature $\frac{1}{c^2}$ surface along principal planes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Intersections by two planes of symmetry $ zOx,zOy $ has the first principal intersection as an ellipse:

$$ \dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{z^2}{b^2}=1 , \; a>b $$

How to find differential equation of the other principal intersection?

If a (0-180) meridian of a sphere is bent to an ellipse shape, how would the (90-270) meridian distort? ..is the actual background question in isometry.

Principal curvature  at center point is $ \dfrac{a^2}{b c^2}$.The curvature along elliptic principal direction is well known.

A pde in Monge form for all points on the distorted surface with standard notation of partial derivatives is:

$$\dfrac{rt-s^2}{(1+p^2+q^2)^{2}}=\dfrac{1}{a^2}$$
that is Monge-Ampère type of pde. Does it have a closed form solution?

If there is none, would n't be easier *at least* to set up and analytically solve an ode on the other principal direction?

Thanks in advance for all indications.

Comment: Please write a complete question.

Comment: Edited the question somewhat.  Is there something else you would like me to include further?

Comment: Do you have a particular surface in mind? There are infinitely many non-compact possibilities.

Comment: None. only a mental picture. I am sure there is a unique solution, upto integration constants/ euclidean motions. A thin hemispherical rubber ball can be hand distorted to visualize  utilizing the Egregium theorem. Please indicate some non compact possibilities.

Comment: Of course you’re wrong. There are spheres and infinitely many twice-punctured spheres that are surfaces of revolution. Perhaps you should study this before being sure.

Comment: I am already aware of these const K =+1 spheres ( generic term) with two openings and spindles.